# CircleCI job is failing, help troubleshoot

Tags: aws-cloudformation, circleci

```
PUBLIC_DNS=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=udapeople-backend-ec2-*' --query "Reservations[*].Instances[0].PublicDnsName" --output text)
echo ${PUBLIC_DNS}
curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
   -H "token: ${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID}" \
   --request PUT \
   --data ${PUBLIC_DNS} \
   https://api.memstash.io/values/public_dns
```

curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Exited with code exit status 2

CircleCI received exit code 2

Comment: After some trouleshooting i got that the following code doesn't work 

`PUBLIC_DNS=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=udapeople-backend-ec2-*' --query "Reservations[*].Instances[0].PublicDnsName" --output text)`

Comment: Actually this line `curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "token: ${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID}" --request PUT --data ${PUBLIC_DNS} https://api.memstash.io/values/public_dns`

Answer (score 1):

your error isn't with Circle CI but with your curl command. The error message is saying it doesn't have a URL to which to PUT. I do see that you included a URL in your curl command, so maybe the problem is in your line endings. Try removing the line endings and run your circle CI job again. You can also try running the command from your local command line.

Answer (score 0):

This is because memstash.io is not working as a website or webservice, there is no issue in your code , memstash is working as a memory-cache for CD jobs so you can find another CD caching service or you have a good option to use circle ci caching itself , try to search for circleCI docs